# Getting Photos on MB Pro and iPhone/iPad/iCloud.com in sync

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

A senior whom I am trying to help with her Photos problem purchased PowerPhotos this morning. We were delighted to find that PowerPhotos was indeed able to merge her old and new Photos libraries and even to save and populate all the folders she had created in Photos.

The problem we now face is that there are roughly 9,000 photos on her newly-merged 2020 MB Pro BUT 40,000 photos on her iPad and iPhone…and in her iCloud.com account.

I have posted in two forums and tried the Apple Support site but cannot find any definitive way to get the photos on all her devices in sync.

Might anyone be able to help her/us get those photos in sync?

Comment: The “problem” is a bit vague - 9K photos on one device and 40K on other devices - but we’re missing is what your desired outcome should be.

Comment: Our presumption is that the 9K of photos on the MB Pro is correct and we would like to arrive at a point where the photos on the iDevices and the MBP are the same... as they are on my iMac, iPhone, and iPad